# neo4j: how to return only specific properties from path

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I match some path and I want that path to be returned. But i don't need whole nodes, I need just their ids. I tried:

```
match path = 
return path {id}
```

but i get syntax error

Answer (score 5):

You can use list comprehension to get just the ids of all nodes in each path (extract() works too):

```
match path = ...
return [node in nodes(path) | id(node)] as nodesInPath
```

This will get you the collection of neo4j internal ids for each node. If you have your own `id` property you're trying to use instead, use `node.id` in the projection portion of the list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
match path = ()--()
unwind(nodes(path)) as nodes
return {id : id(nodes)}
```

Comment: but it returns the individual nodes but not the path itself. i need path. just nodes should be trimmed